# Sonar-Runner not starting (c#)

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

When I start Sonar runner, I am getting this exception. It is not working and not starting. What can I do? Please help me ,thank you. (I am trying to configure Sonar 3.2 in my Windows 7 64 bit operating system)

```
C:\Users\ea\Desktop\sonar-runner-2.0\sonar-runner-2.0\bin>sonar-runner
ôSONAR_RUNNER_HOME = C:\Users\ea\Desktop\sonar-runner-2.0\sonar-runner-2.0\
bin\..ö
ôPROJECT_HOME = C:\Users\ea\Desktop\sonar-runner-2.0\sonar-runner-2.0\bin\.
.ö
Runner configuration file: C:\Users\ea\Desktop\sonar-runner-2.0\sonar-runne
r-2.0\bin\..\conf\sonar-runner.properties
Project configuration file: NONE
Runner version: 2.0
Java version: 1.7.0_07, vendor: Oracle Corporation
OS name: "Windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64"
Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1254" (analysis is platf
orm dependent)
Server: http://localhost:9000  
Work directory: C:\Users\ea\Desktop\sonar-runner-2.0\sonarrunner    2.0\.sonar
13:59:34.477 [main] WARN  o.s.r.i.batch.SonarProjectBuilder - /!\ The 'sources'
property is deprecated and is replaced by 'sonar.sources'. Don't forget to updat
e your files.
13:59:36.207 WARN  .c.p.DefaultDatabase - H2 database should be used for evaluat
ion purpose only
13:59:36.207 INFO      o.s.c.p.Database - Create JDBC datasource to url jdbc:h2:
tcp://localhost/sonar
13:59:37.390 INFO  actDatabaseConnector - Initializing Hibernate
13:59:38.851 WARN  StudioProjectBuilder - The specified '.sln' path does not poi
nt to an existing file: C:\Users\ea\Desktop\sonar-runner-2.0\sonar-runner-2
.0\bin\..\sinav_bildir
Total time: 7.632s
Final Memory: 7M/171M
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: org.picocontainer.P
icoLifecycleException: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public final void org.son
ar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectBuilder.start()', instance 'org.sonar.plugins.csha
rp.core.VisualStudioProjectBuilder@7986f7af, java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper

    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:288)
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:151)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:84)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:56)
Caused by: org.picocontainer.PicoLifecycleException: PicoLifecycleException: met
hod 'public final void org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectBuilder.start()', in
stance 'org.sonar.plugins.csharp.core.VisualStudioProjectBuilder@7986f7af, java.
lang.RuntimeException: wrapper
    at org.picocontainer.monitors.NullComponentMonitor.lifecycleInvocationFa
iled(NullComponentMonitor.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.monitorAndThr
owReflectionLifecycleException(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(
ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:115)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(Reflect
ionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter
.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.j
ava:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Store
d.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(Defaul
tPicoContainer.java:1009)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoConta
iner.java:1002)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.jav
a:760)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentCo
ntainer.java:70)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:82)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.jav
a:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
    at org.sonar.batch.Batch.execute(Batch.java:104)
    at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.Launcher.executeBatch(Launcher.java:6
9)
    at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:285)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.monitorAndThr
owReflectionLifecycleException(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:130)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: No valid '.sln' file could be fou
nd. Please read the previous log messages to know more.
    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.core.VisualStudioProjectBuilder.createVisual
StudioSolution(VisualStudioProjectBuilder.java:169)
    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.core.VisualStudioProjectBuilder.build(Visual
StudioProjectBuilder.java:82)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectBuilder.start(ProjectBuilder.jav
a:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(
ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    ... 23 more
```

Sonar-Project.Properties;

```
# Project identification  
sonar.projectKey=DMG:WindowsFormsApplication2
sonar.projectVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT  
sonar.projectName=my c #
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Info required for Sonar  
sources=.
sonar.language=cs

#Core C# Settings  
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=C:/Users/ea/Desktop/sonar-runner-2.0/sonar-runner-    2.0/bin/WindowsFormsApplication2.sln
#sonar.silverlight.4.mscorlib.location=C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference             Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/Silverlight/v4.0sonar.dotnet.excludeGeneratedCode=true
sonar.dotnet.4.0.sdk.directory=C:/WIndows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319
sonar.dotnet.version=4.0 
#Gendarme  
sonar.gendarme.assemblies=\build\\DmgTech*.*  
sonar.gendarme.mode=skip  

# Gallio  
sonar.gallio.mode=skip  

# FXCop  
sonar.fxcop.installDirectory=C:/Program Files/Microsoft FxCop 1.36
sonar.fxcop.assemblyDependencyDirectories=/bin/Debug

#StyleCop  
sonar.stylecop.mode=skip
```

My folder;

```
WindowsFormsApplication2
WindowsFormsApplication2.sln
sonar-project.properties
sonar-runner.bat
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message is quite straightforward:

```
No valid '.sln' file could be found. Please read the previous log messages to know more.
```

This is because "sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file" property must point an SLN file, not to a folder like what you specified.

What's more, there are too many useless properties in your "sonar-project.properties" file:

- No need to specify the following properties as you set it to their default values:

  - sonar.host.url
  - sonar.jdbc.username
  - sonar.jdbc.password
- You specified "sonar.jdbc.username" and "sonar.jdbc.password" twice...

Comment: sonar-runner properties;
..
..
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=C:\Users\ea\Desktop\sonar-runner-2.0\sonar-runner-2.0\bin\WindowsFormsApplication2.sln
..

It's not working.

Comment: OK, you mixed many things. You shouldn't modify the "sonar-runner.properties" file. Instead, you add a "sonar-project.properties" file at the root of your solution and launch the Sonar Runner from this folder (you don't even have to specify the "sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file" property if the SLN file is in that folder).